# Can't we upload documents/Image using USQL Custom Code and usql?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

**Situation** : We have created database say "CLSTrackOMeter" and table say "Customer_Information" in Azure data lake Analytics.

Customer_Information, stores the path of image in staging folder( For now i've hard code the source image path in class library).

**Agenda** : use that value from CustInfo to upload data to Azure data lake store "Customer_Image" folder

**Tried Solution**
- Created usql class library, using .net sdk to upload files(Able to execute this class library in console application), and deployed in azure data lake store.
- Added new USQL script and referenced this Class library

- Called Class library in cs file of usql script

**Code of Class Library**

```
 using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
    using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.Models;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
    using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace USQLCSharpProject1
    {
        public static class  Program
        {
            private static DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient _adlsClient;
            private static DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient _adlsFileSystemClient;

            private static string _adlsAccountName;
            private static string _resourceGroupName;
            private static string _location;
            private static string _subId;

            //private static void Main(string[] args)
            public static string UploadFileWithS2S_WithClientSecret(string s)
            {

                try
                {
                    _adlsAccountName = "<DATA-LAKE-STORE-NAME>"; // TODO: Replace this value with the name of your existing Data Lake Store account.
                    _resourceGroupName = "<RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME>"; // TODO: Replace this value with the name of the resource group containing your Data Lake Store account.
                    _location = "East US 2";
                    _subId = "<SUBSCRIPTION-ID>";



                    string localFolderPath = @"D:\Harry\PSR\study\TEST"; // TODO: Make sure this exists and can be overwritten.
                    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localFolderPath, "fileTwo.txt"); // TODO: Make sure this exists and can be overwritten.
                    string remoteFolderPath = "/Samples/OUTPUT";
                    //string remoteFilePath = Path.Combine(remoteFolderPath, "file.txt");


                    // Service principal / appplication authentication with client secret / key
// Use the client ID of an existing AAD "Web App" application.
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

var domain = "<AAD-directory-domain>";
var webApp_clientId = "<AAD-application-clientid>";
var clientSecret = "<AAD-application-client-secret>";
 var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(webApp_clientId, clientSecret);
var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain,clientCredential).Result;









                    // Create client objects and set the subscription ID
                    _adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds) { SubscriptionId = _subId };
                    _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);

                    var parameters = new UploadParameters(localFolderPath, remoteFolderPath, _adlsAccountName, isOverwrite: true); // the default  maxSegmentLength is 256M, we can set by ourself.
                    var frontend = new DataLakeStoreFrontEndAdapter(_adlsAccountName, _adlsFileSystemClient);
                    var uploader = new DataLakeStoreUploader(parameters, frontend);
                    uploader.Execute();
                    return s;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

**Code of Usql**

```
USE CLSTrackOMeter;
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY USQLCSharpProject1;
@result =
     SELECT  USQLUploadFile.myFirstClass.myFirstFunction(AgeGender)AS myFirstFunction_CB
    FROM CLSTrackOMeter.dbo.Customer_Information;
```

**Code of USQL cs File**

```
using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace USQLUploadFile
{
    public class myFirstClass
    {
        public static string myFirstFunction(string s)
        {
            try
            {

                string aa = USQLCSharpProject1.Program.UploadFileWithS2S_WithClientSecret("rajni");
                return aa;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }




        }
    }
}
```

**Project Image**
[image]

**Error Image**
[image]

**Error While using PROCESS Expression**
[image]

**USQL Code for PROCESS Expression**

```
USE CLSTrackOMeter;
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY USQLCSharpProject1;
   @result = SELECT AgeGender
    FROM CLSTrackOMeter.dbo.Customer_Information;

    @rs=
    PROCESS @result
    PRODUCE AgeGender
    USING new USQLUploadFile.myFirstClass();


    OUTPUT @rs   
    TO "/output/Harry.csv"
      USING Outputters.Csv();
```

**USQL CS File Process Expression Code**

```
using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace USQLUploadFile
{
    [SqlUserDefinedProcessor]
    public class myFirstClass : IProcessor
    {
        public override IRow Process(IRow input, IUpdatableRow output) 
        {
            try
            {
                string AgeGender = input.Get<string>("AgeGender");
                //USQLCSharpProject1.Class1 obj = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
                //string aa = USQLCSharpProject1.Program.UploadFileWithS2S_WithClientSecret("rajni");
                //return aa;
                string aa=USQLCSharpProject1.Program.UploadFileWithS2S_WithClientSecret("AgeGender");
                output.Set<string>("AgeGender", AgeGender);
                return output.AsReadOnly();

                //return obj.newTest(s);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;

            }



        }
    }
}
```

**addition:**

**After Registring .Net SDK libraries and referring them in USQL**

**Submitting job,shows below text in Output**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.ProjectSystem.ScopeProjectNode.get_ReferenceInfoList()
   at Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Common.ScriptToProjectTable.GetProjectReferenceList(String scriptFilePath)
   at Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.UserInterface.SQLIP.BaseSubmissionViewModel`1.GetScriptContentsWithReference(ProductFunctionType productType)
   at Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.UserInterface.SQLIP.DataLakeJobSubmissionViewModel`1.DoJobSubmission()
```

**Adding Additional Reference Img**
[image]

**Register Assembly in ADLS**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit puzzled in what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to call the Azure SDK calls from within a U-SQL User-defined operator? That will not work since the U-SQL containers do not allows calling web services APIs, including the data lake REST APIs.

Comment: I guess it can run locally and  eventually it is ,but not on ADLS, while reading one of your answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01a3a359-4f13-4535-8a59-e32acbdcf77e/from-a-c-usql-class-assembly-make-an-external-http-web-request-to-get-geo-location-from-ip?forum=AzureDataLake

Comment: So is there's no possibility, if i store my image path in a ADLA table, lets say with value "/sample/image/image1.jpg", and want to use this same path for moving it to other folder in ADLS lets say "/Customer/image/image1.jpg" . Or if i require image at that path to be used as parameter for  cognitive service(FACE API).

Comment: Local run is not running in a container so it does not block you as the server containers will. Also, your local machine has many other options to start a DDOS, so it is less important to block you from doing it ;).

You can copy data in many different ways. I am still not 100% what exactly you want to do, but assuming you have a path inside a table that you want to use in an OUTPUT statement target, you will have to write one script to generate the script that contains the OUTPUT and then run the generated script.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the PROCESS expression ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Mt621322.aspx). A Processor can produce zero or one output rows.

*addition:*

In addition, you need to register the dependent modules as assemblies, as reference them in your U-SQL script (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide#register-u-sql-assemblies):

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
```

Comment: I've just updated the post, after trying PROCESS expression and still facing issue, any suggestion Alexandre, about what i'm missing here.

Comment: Can you show the full exception? You have a MissingMethodException, are you missing some DLLs are your assembly?

Comment: Getting error on Output pain, while doing additional steps suggested, updated screenshot for same

Comment: Clicked on Advanced and Submit the job, it ran successfully, but didn't upload the file

Comment: You should remove the catch blocks that are swallowing exceptions.