# How can we schedule Custom Code Calling Cognitive API in AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-worker-roles, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I've a DLL That downloads image from an IP Camera say at an interval of 4 hrs.

We are targeting to store the downloaded file in AZURE DATA LAKE STORE, say

```
/sample/ImageIPCam1/Image1.jpg
/sample/ImageIPCam1/Image2.jpg
/sample/ImageIPCam1/Image3.jpg
```

After download we need to call cognitive API(FACE API) to check if those three or n images, and select the unique one and store them into Another Folder say

```
/Output/CustImage/Image1.jpg
/Output/CustImage/Image3.jpg
```

Like from above result it is cleared that Image2.jpg was a duplicate one in staging folder.

**So far Implementation **
We tried right custom code using .net sdk to call face api and move image in ADLS but failed on integration with USQL, as i came to know its not allowed [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896225/cant-we-upload-documents-image-using-usql-custom-code-and-usql/43932020#43932020)

**Question/Suggestion Required** :

- What services we should focus in azure to build this setup ?
- How can we automate this custom .NET Class library ?
- Is this possible in Azure Data Factory, appreciate if any case
  studies can be referred?

**Note**
We are targeting storage in ADLS because with this image we are going to store
some details in tables created in ALDA and thereafter need to use to power of USQL for our reports in POWERBIEmbedded.

Answer (score 1):

So to answer your questions...

**What services we should focus in azure to build this setup?**

Stick with the services you have already suggested. Azure Data Lake with the Cognitive assemblies is perfect for this using U-SQL. I've used it a few times in demo's of the language. If you've got errors stick another question on here, but with the U-SQL tag. It'll get answered.

**How can we automate this custom .NET Class library ?**

Within Azure Data Factory create a custom activity which is just an inherited .Net class with an execute method that ADF looks for. ADF will pass DLL's to an Azure Batch Service where the code will actually get executed using a compute pool of VM's.

Check out this blog post on creating custom activities within ADF: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/11/creating-azure-data-factory-custom-activities/

**Is this possible in Azure Data Factory, appreciate if any case studies can be referred?**

Yes, this is certainly possible. I've created data factory solutions for customers very similar to what you've described. We have a case study ready to release pending project sign. Happy to discuss privately.

**A couple of other points to note.**

- Once you've shredded the images with U-SQL and output the object tags to a CSV or whatever you'll need to connect the beta Power BI connector to the ADL store. Currently there isn't a Power BI connector for ADL analytics tables. Wish there was. I feedback this to Microsoft ages ago.
- You'll need to create service principals within the context of your
  Azure Activity Directory to allow the custom activity classes to
  authenticate against data lake store.
- The binaries for the custom activities used by ADF will need to be stored in Azure Blob Storage. The container will be referred as the package linked service in the JSON activity.

For example:

```
"activities": [
{
  "type": "DotNetActivity",
  "typeProperties": {
    "assemblyName": "CustomActivites.dll",
    "entryPoint": "ImageHandler.GetImages",
    "packageLinkedService": "BlobStore", // <<< here
    "packageFile": "CustomActivites.zip",
    "extendedProperties": {
        //if required
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps

Good luck! Happy to assist if required.

Comment: While reading , your blog post and reading about Azure Batch, there are few doubts and if you can give me a few minutes of your time, I'll be much obliged. Looking forward for your contact details @ harsimranjeetsingh@hotmail.com

Comment: Will appreciate, if you can share your ideas to issues in reference question given in post. This is what so far i did to call custom .net sdk library in usql but not getting to any happing endings.

Comment: Happy to assist in a professional capacity. Please email our sales team on sales@purplefrogsystems.com. Thank you